# How to set up a surrogate user on Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse, users

I have a *'work'* user and a *'leisure'* user.

How to I set it up so that one of those users has unfettered access to the other's home folder, so I don't need to constantly switch between the two or manually set permissions in order to transfer files between the home directories?

Specifically I am using OpenSUSE but I assume this is a distro-neutral issue.

Answer (score 1):

Give the user `leisure` access to the existing files and folders in the home folder of `work` using **ACLs**:

```
setfacl -R -m user:leisure:rwx /home/work
```

And then, establish those permisions for new files and folders in */home/work*:

```
setfacl -d -m user:leisure:rwx /home/work
```

---

Traditionally, 3 permission sets are defined for each file object on a Linux system:

- read (r)
- write (w)
- execute (x)

for each of 3 types of users:

- the file owner
- the group
- other users.

**ACLs** is an extension of the traditional file permission concept. They allow the assignment of permissions to individual users or groups even if these do not correspond to the original owner or the owning group.

Comment: Bit busy with work but good answer. I like the extra detail (which I already knew but is great for a QA site). Will accept it if it works, just not had time to truly test it. :)

Answer (score -1):

You probably can't do exactly this unless you make one of the users a "root" user which is a bad idea.

You can get a good part of the way there by using groups, and adding the one user to /etc/group for the other user - in that way any files with appropriate group permissions can be handled by the other user.    You can also set the umask to encourage creation of files with the appropriate group permissions on that users home directory.

Another partial solution might be to use some kind of union filesystem to override default permissions - but the scope of access (ie allowed paths) would need to be worked through, and this is a can of worms.

Comment: Is that a counter downvote? Intriguing. I guess an experienced QAer like yourself will appreciate the lack of answer in your answer, the claim there is no answer yet there is sort of an answer, but you can't be bothered to explain it fully. You'd have been better off not answering instead of that waffle.